# In React, what's the preferred design pattern for communicating data between a nested node and a sibling in a different branch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I have a scenario where I'm a bit confused on how to approach. I feel like there's a lot of refactoring to be done if I were to communicate from the lowest level all the way back up to the parent. I'm very new to using React (a few days now) and I don't know if there's an easier solution to communicate data between components. I've read some sources that said child to parent to other child is best, but I haven't seen mentions of great-great-grandchildren to parent to a child. I've seen mentions about Context API, ComponentDidMount/Update, but I'm not sure what the best approach is.

I'm creating a data explorer on this webpage so we have the RootComponent, LeftPanel, and Graph component.

The LeftPanel holds an Explorer component, which will go through multiple levels of data. On the last level of data, if clicked, it should display a Graph component (through conditional rendering).

ex:

**The Parent**

```
export default class RootComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="flex-row flex-grow">
                <LeftPanel />

                 //Need to conditionally render this
                <Graph />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**LeftPanel is a container within the parent that will hold an explorer**

```
export default class LeftPanel extends React.Component {
  ... (bunch of other logic)

    render() {
        return (
            <Card className="flex-column default-vertical-spacing">
                <div className="content">
                    <Explorer 
                        ..........>
                </div>
            </Card>
        )
    }

}
```

**Explorer holds data as well as a "Pill" or button to click which will show further levels of data**

```
export default class Explorer extends React.Component<IExplorerProps> {

    ... (bunch of logic)

    render() {
      if(!this.props.items || this.props.items.length == 0){
        return <span>Loading</span>
      }
      return ( 
              <ExpandablePill 
              ............../>

      )
    }
}
```

**ExpandablePill is data that can keep going downward**

```
export default class ExpandablePill extends React.Component<ExpandablePillProps, ExpandablePillState> {

    render() {
        ...
        //Here I want to do: If this ExpandablePill was clicked AND it has no children, display a graph.
    }
}
```

**This is under the parent RootComponent but I need to know if an ExpandablePill with no levels left was clicked to display a graph (or make it known to the parent-RootComponent that I can display a graph now)**

```
export default class Graph extends React.Component {  
 render() {
        return (

                        <LineChart
                         ...
                        </LineChart>

        );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Do you have to use class-based components instead of the newer Hooks approach? I think `useContext`  would handle what you are trying to do very neatly if you can use hooks

Comment: I've taken on the project where everything except the Graph was made. I'm open to refactoring but I'm hesitant on rewriting multiple classes. Would using Hooks be a complete refactor?

Comment: Yeah, if you're doing it properly, a complete refactor I'm afraid :-) In the long run it'll simplify things and reduce a lot of pain but it'll take a lot of work and figuring out in the short term. So it depends on how much short-term pressure you're under. Either way, I'd suggest researching having some kind of `isOpen` state in a common ancestor that can be updated in the descendent using context. Maybe try it with the old context API first, then if / when you're ready to switch to hooks in future, it'll be very easy to swap in `useState` and `useContext`

Comment: Refactor of existing presentational components isn't needed. Create a container that uses useContext and get the needed values from context there and have the container render your presentational component passing the values as props. This way your presentational can be pure and not re render if props didn't change (components using useContext will always re render when anything in context changes).